# How to namespace prototype functions?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to put some structure to my JavaScript code and want to add some prototype functions to a namespace, like this:

```
Person.drink();
Person.eat.steak();
```

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
var Person = function() {
    this.thirsty = true;
    this.hungry = true;    

    this.drink();
    this.eat.steak();
}

Person.prototype.drink = function() {
    this.thirsty = false;
}

Person.prototype.eat = {
    steak: function() {
        this.hungry = false;
    }
};

var me = new Person();
console.log(me.thirsty, me.hungry);
```

Console output: `false, true` (Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/upwz4u32/2/)

Why does my nested/namespaced function doesn't have access to it's instance variables?

Comment: because `this` in the second context is `me.eat` http://jsfiddle.net/upwz4u32/3/. try to use `call/apply` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/upwz4u32/4/

Comment: You confuse different concepts. `Person` is a class, not [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
this.eat.steak();
```

Go with

```
this.eat.steak.call(this);
```

As @lordvlad said, in your code this is refering to the eat object of the prototype.

Anyway, defining eat as an object of the prototype defining method itself is weird in my opnion.

Why not go for something like :

```
Person.prototype = {
    eat: function(meat) {
        switch (meat) {
            case "steak":
                this.hungry = false;
            break;
            // ...
        }
    },
    // drink :   
}
```

Comment: It's just an example. There are hundreds of lines of code that I don't want do add inside a switch statement :) `call` does exactly what I want, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Why does my nested/namespaced function doesn't have access to it's instance variables?

Because when you do `me.eat.steak()`, the `this` in the call to `steak` is `eat`, not `me`.

You basically cannot do what you're talking about in ES5 and before without using `call` if you're going to *write* to properties via `this` within `steak`. If you were only going to *read* them, it would be possible by making `eat` an object whose prototype is the instance of `Person`.

In ES6, you could do it by making `eat` a `Proxy` object wrapped around the person instance, but at that point it's getting *really* convoluted.

Instead, either make `eat` a real object that then writes back to its `Person` when necessary, or just use a naming convention (`me.eat$steak()`, for instance).